# I got presented with the same suggested edit review test twice in a row

Tags: bug, review-audits

I got served a suggested edit review test, and I passed! However the next item loaded was exactly the same test...

[image]

Comment: One in a million, perhaps?

Comment: There are known race conditions in review audit selection and who gets served what. What you see is probably due to that. It is unlikely it gets fixed.

Comment: @Stijn [You can never be sure](https://www.random.org/analysis/dilbert.jpg).

Comment: Twice is better than once.

Comment: Well, it either happens, or it doesn't. So I'd say the odds of that happening are about 50-50.